# Proof that the standard topology is the only $T_0$ one that makes $\mathbb R^n$ a TVS?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space. Eric Wofsey's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266859/is-there-an-intrinsic-characterization-of-the-usual-topology-on-a-finite-dimen) post claims

> The usual topology on $V$ is the unique topology that makes $V$ a topological vector space. That is, it is the unique $T_0$ topology that makes addition $V\times V\to V$ and scalar multiplication $\mathbb R\times V\to V$ continuous.

He cites [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445547/how-to-endow-topology-on-a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space) post for details, but as far as I can tell, the answer there only proves the analogous statement for Hausdorff ($T_2$) topologies. I know that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equivalent on a TVS, so the linked answer also proves the above claim with $T_0\to T_1$. But I can't find a proof for the $T_0$ case. **Please prove the above claim.**

Comment: We just need to know that a $T_0$ topological group is Hausdorff, for which see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593365/a-t-0-topological-vector-space-is-hausdorff