# A locally convex space has a topology given by a single norm if the topology is generated by finitely many seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

This is a problem 1a from section V in Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis. It states:

> 1a. Prove that a locally convex space has a topology given by a single norm if the topology is generated by finitely many seminorms

I have seen a few similar questions on here but they make the additional assumption that the space is Hausdorff or use the second part of this problem which states

> 1b. Prove that a locally convex space has a topology generated by a single norm if and only if 0 has a bounded neighborhood.

I would like to prove the problem without assuming the Hausdorff property and without using the (1b).

Let $\{\rho_i\}$ be a collection of seminorms that generate the topology where $i = 1, \ldots, n$. I am thinking of creating a norm using a linear combination of the $\{\rho_i\}$, or perhaps a directed family of them. However, I am not sure how any linear combination of the $\{\rho_i\}$ will necessarily satisfy the positive definite condition of a norm. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: It's not true.  A norm topology is always Hausdorff.  A locally convex space can be defined by a finite family of seminorms that is not separating and so is not Hausdorff.  For example, on $\Bbb{R}^n$ take the seminorms $\rho_i((x_1,\dots,x_n)) =|x_i|$, but let $i$ run over a *proper* subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, Reed & Simon's definition of a locally convex space requires that the seminorms separate points but I had forgotten this detail. It seems to me that we can consider $\sum \rho_i$ to construct a norm so all that is left to prove is that the topology in this norm is the same as the ones generated by the seminorms. Is this correct?

Comment: Seminorms separate points $\implies$ for every $x\ne 0$ there is an open neighborhood of $0$ not containing $x$ $\implies$ the space is $T_0$ $\implies$ the space is Hausdorff (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593365/a-t-0-topological-vector-space-is-hausdorff)).

Comment: You said you already saw proofs of this when the space is Hausdorff, and seminorms separate points implies the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, I will have a look at that link.

Comment: Actually, a simpler proof separating implies Hausdorff.  For $x\ne 0$ let $\rho$ be a seminorm such that $\rho(x) > 0$.  Let $\epsilon = \rho(x)/3$.  Then $\{y:\rho(y) < \epsilon\}$ and and $\{y:\rho(x-y)<\epsilon\}$ are disjoint open neighborhoods of $0$ and $x$.

Comment: Also, for the problem itself it's probably convenient to take the max norm $\|x\|=\max_i \rho_i(x)$.  To prove two topologies on a TVS are the same all you need to show is that an open neighborhood of zero in one one topology contains an open neighborhood of zero in the other topology and vice versa.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, that is really helpful. I think that more or less solves 1b as well.